# Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ScriptURL -UseBasicParsing adds ? at the starting of sql query. Due to which getting : Invoke-Sqlcmd:Incorrect syntax near‘?’

Tags: sql-server, powershell, automation, jenkins-plugins, powershell-cmdlet

I’m trying to read a SQL script file from github using

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ScriptUrl -UseBasicParsing
```

and then trying to execute this script in my local SQL Server using

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlinstance -database $db -query $qry
```

but am getting error:

> Invoke-SqlCmd: Incorrect Syntax near ‘?’

I tried to use

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $ScriptUrl -UseBasicParsing
```

but this time also getting the same issue.

Comment: please add the url to the source and also how `$qry` variable was set

Comment: Is it actually a `?` character or is it byte order mark/preamble indicating UTF8/UCS2 encoding of the downloaded T-SQL? Have you tried persisting the query to a file on disk and inspecting it with a hex editor yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for the issue. I used Remove(0,1) as '?' mark was appended at the starting.
Let me show the cmdlets:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
#set variables
$GitRepository = "/XYZ/ProjectName/main/DB"
$GitManifestArray =@("Script1.sql","Script2.sql","Script3.sql","StoredProcedures.sql","Script4.sql","Script5.sql")
$SQLInstances = ".\SQLEXPRESS"

ForEach ($SQLInstance in $SQLInstances.Split(","))
{
  echo "Running Scripts on " $SQLInstance
  ForEach ($file in $GitManifestArray)
  {
     $ScriptURL = ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com" + 
     $GitRepository+"/"+$file.Replace("/blob/","/"))
     $ScriptFromGit = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ScriptURL -UseBasicParsing
     $qry=$($ScriptFromGit.Content).Remove(0,1)
     Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance  -Query $qry
 }}
```

But still I don't know why '?' is being added at the starting of Script1.sql(For me its Database.sql).